# flutter floor floor_generator error: There are no entities added to the database annotation

Tags: android, flutter, dart, floor

I have created the floor entities and DAOs
but when I run

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

I got the following error

> There are no entities added to the database annotation.
> package:storeapp/database/myAppDatabase.dart:74:16    ╷ 74 │ abstract
> class MyAppDatabase extends FloorDatabase {}    │

but I added the entities as following

```
@Database(version: 1, entities: [
  Account,
  AccountingClass,
  LocalizedProperty,
  PointOfSale,
  StoreCurrencyMapping,
  User,
  InventoryTransaction,
  JournalVoucher,
  JournalVoucherEntry,
  JournalVoucherEntryDetail,
  BaseObject,
  StoreCustomer,
  StoreEmployee,
  StoreVendor,
  Store,
  Warehouse,
  Category,
  Product,
  ProductCategory,
  StoreProductMapping,
  Order
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was importing a file as

```
import 'models/baseObjects/Warehouse.dart';
```

the capital in the file name, when I change it to exactly the file name as

```
import 'models/baseObjects/warehouse.dart';
```

it works fine.